# Waiting for coroutine finish before fragment close

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my View Model I have created a function that uploads audio file to Firebase Storage.Then I want to close my fragment but only if the file was already uploaded so I have to wait for coroutine to complete job. How can I achieve it? I can use *runBlocking* and it works but I don't think that's a good idea.

```
fun addRequest(request: Event){
    scope.launch {
        val uri = repository.uploadAudioFile()
        request.audio = uri
        repository.addRequest(request)
    }
}
```

Then in my fragment I want to call something like:

```
 prosbyViewModel.addRequest(Event(title = title,description = description, date = date))
 requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

Comment: Dow does uploadAudioFile function look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the function that launches a coroutine return the Job, so you can wait for it in other coroutines:

```
fun addRequest(request: Event): Job = viewModelScope.launch {
    val uri = repository.uploadAudioFile()
    request.audio = uri
    repository.addRequest(request)
}
```

Then, in your Fragment, you can `join()` the job in another coroutine, so you're waiting for it without blocking the main thread. I think you probably want to freeze other UI, so you may want to set up your layout so it can disable your UI when it reaches this state.

```
viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope.launch {
    disableTheUi()
    prosbyViewModel.addRequest(Event(title = title,description = description, date = date))
        .join()
    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}
```

Alternatively, you can make it a suspend function to begin with so it is always called from a coroutine and waited for without the need for `join()`:

```
suspend fun addRequest(request: Event) {
    val uri = repository.uploadAudioFile()
    request.audio = uri
    repository.addRequest(request)
}
```

One possible way to disable the whole UI would be to change your fragment's layout so the top level view is a FrameLayout containing your original layout, plus one more layout that shows a indeterminate progress bar. To disable the UI, set the original layout's top view to invisible, and set the progress bar's layout to visible.

Answer (score 0):

You might think about doing your upload in the background, not in the viewmodel itself.

The currently suggested way of doing this is via workmanager, see https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

> WorkManager is the recommended solution for persistent work. Work is
> persistent when it remains scheduled through app restarts and system
> reboots. Because most background processing is best accomplished
> through persistent work, WorkManager is the primary recommended API
> for background processing.